# excel - if column against other column

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I have **two** excel sheets. One like below:

*Sheet 1:*

```
Column 1    Column 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
Date 1      Date 2
```

*Sheet 2:*

```
Column 1:   
On Time:      xx
Not on Time:  xx
```

So example.

If date 1 is greater than date 2, then it should add 1 to the "Not on time" row. And if date 1 is less than **or** equals date 2, then it should add 1 to the "On Time" row.

*Please note that I have two different sheets in the same workbook*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array Formulas` is one possibility. Note: With `Array Formulas`, you have to confirm them by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Not on time: `=SUM(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26)<=(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$26),1,0))`

On Time: `=SUM(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$26)<=(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$26),1,0))`

Does that do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a dummy column. Make your sheet look like this
Sheet1

```
A           B           C
Date 1      Date 2      1
Date 1      Date 2      1
Date 1      Date 2      0
Date 1      Date 2      1
Date 1      Date 2      1
Date 1      Date 2      1
Date 1      Date 2      0
Date 1      Date 2      0
Date 1      Date 2      0
```

Sheet2

```
A   
On Time:      xx
Not on Time:  xx
```

---

The column C holds a 1 if A<=B in that row and 0 otherwise (A>B).

Now

- edit your On Time cell to `="Not on time: " & COUNTIF($C$1:$C$15; 0)`
- edit your Not on Time cell to `="Not on time: " & COUNTIF($C$1:$C$15; 1)`

I tested it and it should work to your liking. Let's hope you have the freedom to manipulate the sheet layout.